# Mvc Jquery page size change calls action and rebinds list on view

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Really stuck with this.. I have a page size drop down on the page and I need to write some jquery to call the action and rebind the grid in my view. I have got the following

```
        if (selectNode.selectedIndex == 0) {
            $.get("user/index", { pageSize: "10" })
        }
        if (selectNode.selectedIndex == 1) {
            $.get("user/index", { pageSize: "20" })
            .done(function (data) {
                alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            });
        }
```

This calls the action with the correct page size value call my rest service with the correct value but never rebinds the page. What have i missed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `selectNode.selectedIndex` is it integer indeed? What does `console.log(typeof(selectNode.selectedIndex))` says about it?

Comment: this isnt the problem.. the problem is even though I am calling my action with the correct parameters and the object is returning the correct results. It is not updating to the page html